# Hosting a website on your own server

Tags: linux, dns, web-hosting

Is there a detailed guide which explains how to host a website on your own server on linux.
I have currently hosted it on one of the commerical web-hosts.
Also the domain is registered to a different vendor.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This guide](http://gentoo-wiki.com/HOWTO_setup_a_home-server) is probably more info than you really requested, but webserver information is in there.  It's Gentoo-specific, but you can apply the same information with minor translations to any other distro.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how familiar you are with linux. Certainly, many people do this for hobbyist websites.

There are many aspects involved - you should begin with something simple like getting apache running and visible to the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into installing apache

99% of linux distributions will have a package for it.

On ubuntu you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Are you considering hosting a web page locally for the internet? Or is this just for development etc..

If it's for an internet server, you will need a stable internet connection with a good upstream.

You may also need a static IP address so you can setup DNS to point to the right place.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have an url to a good tutorial in english, I would just warn you that this is not something you should take lightly. Administrating a server involves getting your hands dirty in linux stuff and dealing with security can be pretty complex depending on your knowledge and requirements.

So if you know nothing about it, you should be very careful and if the website you host has is of any commercial importance you are probably better off hiring a server admin.

Comment: Hi Seldaek,

Thanks for your insights. Right now, i am just testing the waters, so to speak. When it does reach commerical scales, i would keep your suggestions in mind.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out; if this is a personal (home) server, as opposed to one in a corporate environment, then it's better not to bother hosting it - you won't necessarily have the bandwidth, and your ISP may not allow it.

As mentioned above, you will also need a static IP address, and you'll need to set up DNS records to point to the correct location, which your domain vendor may or may not help you with.